# Creating a select menu from variables and arrays

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out how I can create a select menu that has the variable '$portfolios' number of options, but only show the option if the array $portfolio_list has less than 3 in the array segment that corresponds to the option.

So for example. There are 2 portfolios, with 2 assigned to the first, and 1 assigned to the second. So I need two options created in my select, both available.

```
$portfolios = '2';

$portfolios_list = array(2,1);
```

If the first option has 3 assigned as below, I would only want the second to appear as an option.

```
$portfolios = '2';

$portfolios_list = array(3,1);
```

I also need the option to carry the correct number. So 1, or 2. If 1 is hidden, the only option would show 2.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can access parts of the array like so

```
$portfolios_list[0]; //in your second example this would equal 3
$portfolios_list[1]; //in your second example this would equal 1
```

So do something like

```
if($portfolios_list[0] != '3'){
YOUR CODE
}
```

that just says if it is not 3 execute  YOUR CODE

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the argument that you are in `$portfolios_list`  accessing has a value less than 3. If it has then add this mark up to your  element-

```
<option value="..">...</option>
```